# Cannot set Angular scope variable from within ajax call

Tags: angularjs, ajax, scope

```
var req = {
            "RequestId": $scope.$parent.req_id,
            "RequestDate": new Date(),
            "RequestDetails": $scope.$parent.details
        };

$scope.req_result = "test";

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:49358/api/myClasses/PostRequest',
            data: JSON.stringify(req),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            processData: true,
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("The result is : " + status);
                $scope.req_result = "Post succeeded";
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                $scope.req_result = "ERROR: " + xhr.responseText
            }
        });
```

The scope variable $scope.req_result does not get set so when I attempt to display it on the html view page:

```
<span>{{req_result}}</span>
```

it displays the default value. Somehow what ajax is doing is not known to angular

Comment: are you sure the ajax callbacks are being reached?

Comment: you should use `$.ajax` here, use `$http` instead, wouldn't make you bother to run digest cycle..

Comment: Does using $http have serious advantages? other then not having to run digest cycle?

Comment: Yes, look at the code below that uses $http. Angular internally does a lot of things that you are doing manually like setting content-type header, creating JSON from JavaScript object etc. Angular core itself comes with $http, so you might as well use it to your benefit. If Ajax is the only thing you are using jQuery for, you can go ahead and remove that dependency even.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to initiate the digest cycle by calling `$scope.$apply()` after you modify the scope variable from non-angular context.

```
success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    $scope.req_result = "Post succeeded";
    $scope.$apply();
},
error: function (xhr) {
    $scope.req_result = "ERROR: " + xhr.responseText
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Angular does the magical view updates by creating something called "**watchers**". When you do `{{ someScopeVariable }}`, Angular is creating watcher for that scope variable. Just as when you programmatically create a watcher by doing

```
$scope.$watch('someScopeVariable', function myListenerFunction() {
    // When someScopeVariable changes, do this
});
```

Watchers go hand-in-hand with something called **digest cycle**. From different places within Angular, e.g. $timeout callback, or $http.then() callback etc., Angular invokes the digest cycle from the $rootScope. This is basically going through all the watchers in the scope and if the value being watched has changed, invoke the listener function like the *myListenerFunction* above.

Important thing is Angular is triggering this digest cycle internally. So, when you use $.ajax() from jQuery, you are missing this. You change the scope variable that are being watched because you did

{{req_result}}

but, no watchers know about it. `$scope.$apply()` makes sure all the watchers know about this change by initiating a digest cycle from the root scope.

**BUT**

A better solution to your issue would be to use Angular's internal $http service which can be used to make XHR request and Angular automatically triggers digest cycle when you callback functions are invoked.

```
var req = {
            "RequestId": $scope.$parent.req_id,
            "RequestDate": new Date(),
            "RequestDetails": $scope.$parent.details
        };

$scope.req_result = "test";

$http
    .post('http://localhost:49358/api/myClasses/PostRequest', req)
    .then(
        function () {
            $scope.req_result = "Post succeeded";
        }, 
        function () {
            $scope.req_result = "ERROR";
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm

Comment: Please read the edit to understand why it worked and what is the better solution.

Comment: Wanted to thank you again for such a detailed answer