# Angular js $scope is not working inside Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using Sweet alert for alert messages. I have confirmation alert box is there, after confirmation i have disable my content but that is not disable `$scope` is not working inside `swal()` if clicked twice it is working.how can i make it work. 
My HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">

    Supplier ID:<input type="text" ng-model="supplierID" ng-disabled="disable"/><br>
    Series ID:<input type="text" ng-model="seriesID" ng-disabled="disable"/><br>
    SKU ID:<input type="text" ng-model="skuID" ng-disabled="disable"/><br><br>
    <div class="action-keys">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="enable()" ng-disabled="!disable">Enable</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="disableCall()" ng-disabled="disable">Disable</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

and my `myscript.js`:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.disable = false;
     $scope.disableCall = function () {
        swal(
            {
            title: 'Warning',text: 'Are you want to disable?',type: 'warning',showCancelButton: true,confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes',cancelButtonText: 'No',confirmButtonClass: 'confirm-class',cancelButtonClass: 'cancel-class',allowOutsideClick : false
        },function(isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                $scope.skuID = '';
                $scope.seriesID = '';
                $scope.supplierID = '';
                $scope.disable = true;
            }else{
                return;
            } 
        });
    }
    $scope.enable = function () {
        $scope.skuID = '';
        $scope.seriesID = '';
        $scope.supplierID = '';
        $scope.disable = false;

    }
});
```

This my sample code enable is working fine, disable function inside confirm not working. Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when update scope outside angular context you need to notify angular to run a digest in order to see changes reflected in view

Comment: @charlietfl- how can i notify. I'm new to AngularJs. Please help.

Comment: @charlietfl is right. try using $scope.$apply() ;

Comment: @Jannik- where i need to insert that statement.

Comment: see @medet-tleukabiluly answer

Comment: @Rajesh checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326062/cannot-set-angular-scope-variable-from-within-ajax-call to understand why $scope.$apply fixes your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `$scope.$apply` when something happening outside of angular. Notice the call

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    //everything here will trigger digest cycle
    //everything...
});
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.disable = false;
     $scope.disableCall = function () {
        swal(
            {
            title: 'Warning',text: 'Are you want to disable?',type: 'warning',showCancelButton: true,confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes',cancelButtonText: 'No',confirmButtonClass: 'confirm-class',cancelButtonClass: 'cancel-class',allowOutsideClick : false
        },function(isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                  $scope.skuID = '';
                  $scope.seriesID = '';
                  $scope.supplierID = '';
                  $scope.disable = true;
                });
            }else{
                return;
            } 
        });
    }
    $scope.enable = function () {
        $scope.skuID = '';
        $scope.seriesID = '';
        $scope.supplierID = '';
        $scope.disable = false;

    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">

    Supplier ID:<input type="text" ng-model="supplierID" ng-disabled="disable"/><br>
    Series ID:<input type="text" ng-model="seriesID" ng-disabled="disable"/><br>
    SKU ID:<input type="text" ng-model="skuID" ng-disabled="disable"/><br><br>
    <div class="action-keys">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="enable()" ng-disabled="!disable">Enable</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="disableCall()" ng-disabled="disable">Disable</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you could also consider wrapping it in a `$timeout` callback with no duration parameter, it will wait until the current digest is complete and kick off another one, it avoids calling `$apply` while a digest is still running.

Comment: @paultrone- If that improves the solution, please post your answer.